How to update log stream name in CloudWatch in AWS using fluent bit
I am interested in pod logs. I am trying to ship logs from AWS EKS to cloudwatch using below fluent-bit deamon set in EKS
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-container-insights/latest/k8s-deployment-manifest-templates/deployment-mode/daemonset/container-insights-monitoring/fluent-bit/fluent-bit.yaml
I am applying it, but it creates the log stream in format. How can I just have instance name and pod name in it? Can someone help?
The current format is
ip-10-11-97-64.ec2.internal-application.var.log.containers.sonarqube-sonarqube-dce-search-0_sonarqube-dce_sonarqube-dce-search-b892adb2fbf60a36568c3578c20181941dc8f6d00a8180cb837f9f76ecaa515a.log

I am interested to have log stream name as instancename_namespacename_podname

This is totally possible using the variables log_stream_name or if you want some regex log_stream_prefix in ConfigMap resource before applying it.
You can download the yaml from the Github raw link, then edit it by changing in the ConfigMap:
log_stream_prefix   ${HOST_NAME}.

to something like:
log_stream_prefix    /eks/$(kubernetes['namespace_name'])/$(kubernetes['pod_name'])

